# Is there a security risk in having my bookmarks publicly accessible?

Tags: web-browser

I'm considering storing my web browsing bookmarks in my Github repository as I use several different browsers in different locations and haven't found a satisfactory method of syncing bookmarks between browsers.

My concern is that my bookmarks will be publicly accessible and on a website which identifies me and so could be used to determine information about me such as:

- who I bank with
- which email providers I use
- etc.

Or should I just not worry about it?

Comment: xmarks does what you want. And many other providers.

Comment: Thanks @ISMSDEV but I've had issues with Xmarks misbehaving and it doesn't work with the Firefox Developer Edition due to the change in the way plugins work, although I suspect a compatible version will be released later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question.

I would not be happy leaking that level of detail. It would let me build a pretty good picture of who you are, your interests, hints on your personal details, as you mention your bank, email etc.

There is also a good chance if you are not careful, to end up storing a whole bunch of potentially sensitive get params in the bookmark URLs.

This would be as bad, potentially worse, than having your social media profiles public.

If you are set on GitHub pay for private repos or use another authenticated cloud storage solution.

Comment: Thanks, I think the authenticated website approach is probably the most sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes storing your bookmarks in a public domain could be a security concern. Whether you think the risk is acceptable is down to personal appetite levels though.

Some risks could include:

- A targeted attacker can build up a profile of sites you visit, allowing them to pull of phishing attacks easier and other similar social engineering attacks
- A bookmark could include querystring data that identifies something you would not want to be made public. Such as an ID for a transaction for example.
- You might include a bookmark that you would rather not be made public (maybe you've seen a job at a competitor you want to read later on)